# No mfc100d.dll while remote debugging

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Trying to organize remote debugging procedure: 
 1. Installed remote debugging tool to remote machine without problem. 
 2. Copy executable and pdb file to remote machine.
 3. Set Visual C++ to debug remotely

After Start Debugging execution I have message that mfc100d.dll is missing. Should I copy this dll manually from mine machine or it might be installed somehow in different way?

Comment: The only possible mistake you could make is not trying it.

Comment: The checked (debug) versions of those DLL's are not redistributeable and not available in an installation package separate from apps like VS. The logical option is to just copy the DLL's from your dev machine over to the remote target.

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugging is typicaly used to debug production machines or QA machines - which should run non-debug ('release') builds only.   Seems you are trying to deploy and remote-debug a 'debug' build. Are you sure you want to do that?   If so - Why?

If there is indeed a valid reason, you'd need debug versions of *all* the redist dll's, much more than mfc alone.  (You'd copy mfc100d.dll and it would immediately shout about missing msvcr100d.dll or something).   I don't have access to VS2010 right now, but in VS2013 the needed dll's are concentrated under %VS_INSTALL_DIR%\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist. You could try and copy all of them to the remote path you're executing from.

But again, please be very sure there's a good reason to do so.